# Issue while configuring site acess for Multi-Site over same drupal content using domain access module

Tags: 7, multi-sites, migrations, domain-access

I have a drupal site with over 100k nodes. I now need to add 2 more domains and share teh content across these domains. Using `Domain access module` i have created the domains and made content type default to all domains. This works great for new nodes.

However, i cant figure out how to bulk assign existing nodes to all. VBO doesnt seem to have a `domain access` integration. Domain content does allow bulk updation but thats only 50 nodes at a time. Doing 100k will take a massive amount of time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For initial level do you want to add all node in all domain? If that you can use migrate module for better approach.

Comment: yup i need to have all nodes in all the domain

Comment: @rameshbabu ok so i installed the module but cant really figure out what to do. Will this require custom coding? Can you please helpme with some more details. (PS: Excuse my basic questions, am not a hardcore developer)